# How to use trim with array_map in PHP

Tags: php, array-map, character-trimming

I am trying to remove two characters from the end of each line (if they exist) in an array map.

These characters do not always exist

So I am trying to convert

```php
Array ( [0] => C7130A-B [1] => RB2-8120 [2] => RM1-1082-000B [3] => 0950-4768B [4] => C7130B )
```

to

```php
Array ( [0] => C7130A [1] => RB2-8120 [2] => RM1-1082-000 [3] => 0950-4768 [4] => C7130 )
```

Basically I am trying to Eliminate B or -B from the end, I have found a way to do this on a string but cannot on an array.

I have tried many options I have found here on Stack and have sadly had no luck.

```php
function cleanit($s) {
    return rtrim($s, "B");
}

$words = strtoupper($words);
$toBeFound = explode(PHP_EOL, $words);
$war = array_map('cleanit', $toBeFound);
echo('Begin<br>');
print_r($war); 
echo('<br>End');
```

So far the best result I have had is to remove the B (or -B) from the last item in the array. Which is the result of this code.

```php
Array ( [0] => C7130A-B [1] => C7130B [2] => RM1-1082-000B [3] => 0950-4768B [4] => C7130 )
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) that provides what you needed.

Code sample:

```
function cleanit($s) {
  // return rtrim($s, "B");
  $b = strrpos($s,"B");
  $-b = strrpos($s,"-B");

  if($-b > -1) return str_replace($s,"-B");
  if($b > -1) return str_replace($s,"B");
  return $s;
}
```

Comment: This solution here is returning an empty array for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex with preg_replace like this ($ for remove only on the end of string) :

```
$myArray = array('C7130A-B', 'RB2-8120', 'RM1-1082-000B', '0950-4768B', 'C7130B');
function cleanit($val)
{
    return preg_replace('/(-B|B)$/','',$val);
}
$resultArray = array_map('cleanit', $myArray);
print_r($resultArray);

Array ( [0] => C7130A [1] => RB2-8120 [2] => RM1-1082-000 [3] => 0950-4768 [4] => C7130 )
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace()` is perfectly equipped to trim the optional hyphen and `B` from the end of all strings in your array.

`$` will match the end of a given string. `?` means zero or one of the preceding expression (the hyphen).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/noQca))

```
var_export(
    preg_replace('/-?B$/', '', $array)
);
```